# Изменить фон TPageControl (вкладок и основной области)

Tags: delphi, themes, delphi-11-alexandria

Работаю в Delphi 11 Alexandria.
Кидаю на форму TPageControl. Фон контрола – белый. Сделать его серым (вернее, clBtnFace) можно, отключив Runtime Themes (в настройках манифеста проекта). Однако, результат получается не очень красивым, т.к. отключаются стили. Особенно удручает TProgressBar в стиле Windows 2000. Ещё один вариант – применить `SetWindowTheme(MyPageControl.Handle, nil, '')` , однако стили в этом случае так же отключаются.

Вопрос: можно ли как-то поменять фон PageControl'а (вкладок и основной области) без изменения остальных элементов стиля? Может, через WinAPI, через манипуляции со стилями (VCL или Winapi.UxTheme)?

Comment: [Смена цвета вкладки PageControl](https://www.cyberforum.ru/delphi-beginners/thread2440558.html)

Comment: @zed, это не то. Там отключается стиль. По сути, это то же самое, что я описал выше. Но мне нужно *сохранить* стиль, изменив только цвет фона. Может, какие-нибудь TStyleHook нужно использовать (не работал в этим ни разу, не представляю как это делается)?

Comment: а использовать сторонние компоненты? Например TJVPageControl из пакета JVCL https://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:TJvPageControl.Color (Delphi 11 нет, проверить не могу). Потенциально можно даже готовые формы без особой проблемы перевести целиком на компоненты проекта (вместо T вставить TJv и чаще всего без проблем).

Comment: Там же внутри ещё ссылка есть на то, как и со стилями делать: [Creating colorful tabsheets with the VCL Styles](https://theroadtodelphi.com/2012/04/12/creating-colorful-tabsheets-with-the-vcl-styles/).

Comment: красивый pagePanelConstrols на основе TPanel альтернатива TpageControl
https://github.com/dvb01/PanelPageControl